# Suppress doesn't work in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

i need to suppress column-1 values, if another column-2 was not changed.

i put formula to suppress column-1 like

```
if {Column-2}=previous({Column-2}) then true else false
```

but sometimes it is not suppressing. I even showed in the report values of **previous({Column-2})** to make sure they are changed

Can you advise, what am i doing wrong?

[please check attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYirI.png)

Comment: Instead you can try using option `select distinct records`

Comment: Records are not similar already, few columns are.
There are other columns that are not mentioned here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i figured it out.
It was sql, who returned blank fields, not a suppression.
So guys, also don't forget to check what exactly your sql is returning